# Python project to debian package for installing with apt-get

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, apt, deb

A lot of similar questions were here, but I have a solid confusion.

**[1] I want to try the best way to package my python project with third-party modules into .deb package and than install all of things with apt-get utillity.**

My guess how to do this:

- Create a `virtualenv`.
- Install all third-party python modules using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
- But my problem is that I can't find a full guide how to package that environment into the .deb file.

And another question: **[2] is python virtual environment cross-platform? I mean: do I have to create the environment in the same OS as the OS for distribution?**

Comment: https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv may work for you

Comment: @emulbreh yeah, I saw it, but I didn't understand this sequence: *Only requirement is that your project has a somewhat sane setup.py and requirements listed in a requirements.txt file. Note however that defining any requirements is not mandatory*.

Comment: It needs a setup.py file for your project: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#setup-py